# Extrayendo datos de un archivo txt para crear una variable en Python

Tags: python, xml, archivo, variables, text

estoy tratando de extraer los datos de un archivo.xml para crear una serie de variables que poder almacenar en un diccionario en python. Mi código para ello sería:

```
    with open(data["cfg"], 'r') as file:
    zinput = str("<dataUno>")
    dataUno = 0
    dataDos = ""
    dataTres = 0
    dataCuatro = ""
    for line in file:
        if zinput in line:
            dataUno = zinput.split(">", 0)
            print(dataUno)
```

El archivo xml en cuestión tiene la información organizada de la siguiente manera:

```
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <variablesEntrada>
        <variable>
            <dataUno>45</dataUno>
            <dataDos>NT</dataDos>
            <dataTres>1</dataTres>
            <dataCuatro>SI</dataCuatro>
        </variable>
        <variable>
            <dataUno>5</dataUno>
            <dataDos>NTPI</dataDos>
            <dataTres>13</dataTres>
            <dataCuatro>TRE</dataCuatro>
        </variable>
    </variablesEntrada>
</config>
```

`

Pretendo crear una variable en Python para cada una de las que hay en el XML, para así introducirlas en un diccionario clave:valor con el siguiente código:

```
class ConfigVariableData:

def __init__(self, dataUno, dataDos, dataTres, dataCuatro):
    self.dataUno = dataUno
    self.dataDos = dataDos
    self.dataTres = dataTres
    self.dataCuatro = dataCuatro
```

El caso es que no se como sacar específicamente los datos entre los . He probado con split pero me estoy haciendo la picha un lío.

Comment: Por qué no utilizas ElementTree?

Comment: La clase que estás usando no es un diccionario clave-valor sino una clase. El diccionario sería más bien `diccionario["dataUno"] = dataUno`. Esto sí que se puede crear sin problemas pues `"dataUno"` (la clave) es una cadena que puede estar en una variable. Así:  `clave = "dataUno"; valor=dataUno; diccionario[clave] = valor`

Comment: Vale, al final lo he hecho tirando de ElementTree y he creado además correctamente el diccionario clave:valor. Gracias a los dos!